# Struct and a symbol array

Tags: c, string, struct, malloc, buffer

can you help me? 
i have a problem with `char* station;`
when i fill my gaps, everithing is alright, but when i am with  `printf("%d)Input its stations: ",i+1);`. It's a problem, i mean: i enter `chech-joch-chor-dsh-dsh` but i need to enter `chech joch chor dsh dsh`(these are names of stations,it's an example).So it prints **ONLY THE FIRST WORD**, i dont why.. check this out please... (i understand that i need to free what i'have taken). Please, explain why it is so, why the first?.. give me a hint..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct info_bus_{
    int number;
    int begin;
    int end;
    char* stations;
    int time_working;
}info_bus;


int main()
{

    info_bus *b=NULL;
    int i,n;
    char buffer[128];
    printf("How many buses u have: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    b=(info_bus *)malloc(n*sizeof(info_bus));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Input the number of a bus: ");
    scanf("%d",&(b+i)->number);

    printf("%d)Input when it starts to work: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(b+i)->begin);

    printf("%d)Input when it  finishes to work: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&(b+i)->end);

        printf("%d)Input its stations: ",i+1);
        scanf("%127s", buffer);
        b[i].stations = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(b[i].stations, buffer);

    printf("Input time working: ");
    scanf("%d",&(b+i)->time_working);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n[%d].the number of a bus: %d",i+1,b->number);
        printf("\n[%d]. Begin at: %d",i+1,b->begin);
        printf("\n[%d]. Finishes at: %d",i+1,b->end);
        printf("\n[%d]. Stations: %s",i+1,b->stations);
        printf("\n[%d]. Time working: %d",i+1,b->time_working);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when i use `gets()`
it is: 
[image]

Comment: `%s` of `scanf` reads as whilte-space separator. So It doesn't include spaces in contents.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how should it fix?

Comment: See also [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: `scanf("%127s", buffer);` --> `scanf(" %127[^\n]%*c", buffer);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, it helped me:) i understood what you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    scanf("%127s", buffer);
```

stops reading after encountering a newline. If you want to be able to read multiple words then use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html):

```
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

Note: `fgets()` will also read the newline character if there's room. You can remove it if necessary:

```
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0; /* to remove the newline */
```

Generally, avoid using `scanf()` even for other inputs. It's error prone. See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Also, the cast of malloc() is unncessary. See: [What's wrong with casting malloc's return value?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. Use `fgets()` instead. The reason for your problem is `fgets()` will stop reading input after a newline. But the previous `scanf()` leaves a newline. That's why you shouldn't mix `fgets()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: please, look at my question, i've chaged it. when i use `gets()`. it happens me it

Comment: `"Input when it  finishes to work:"`  and `"Input its stations:" `at the same  line

Comment: You'll have to read out the newline character: just use `getchar()` right before calling `fgets()`. But I'd recommend avoiding `scanf()` altogether.

Comment: Thank you for helping , used `getchar()` and `scanf(" %127[^\n]%*c", buffer);`,now it works.  But i also got that i shouldnt use `scanf()`.. Can you  the right code of my program with `fgets()`. FIX ME:)  If you can. Thanks, for helping one more time